# Buildozer выдает ошибку (Python+Kivy)

Tags: python, kivy

При компиляции Buildozer простого приложения на связке Python+Kivy вываливается туча предупреждений и ошибка:

```
[WARNING]: Could not find toolchain subdirectory!
[WARNING]: Could not find any toolchain for arm-linux-androideabi!
[WARNING]: Missing executable: autoconf is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: automake is not installed
[WARNING]: Missing executable: libtoolize is not installed
[ERROR]:   python-for-android cannot continue; aborting
# Command failed: /home/jjetspace/TableBus/bin/python -m 
pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 -
-requirements=kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --
storage-dir=/home/jjetspace/PycharmProjects/Hello/ 
.buildozer/android/platform/build
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Помогите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для сборки apk пакета требуется Linux система, либо ее образ на виртуальной машине. 
Почитайте [эту статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/301776/).